# How to replace `require` function while upgrading a NodeJS project to TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, file-conversion

I am trying to modify an existing NodeJS project from JavaScript to TypeScript but I don't know how to deal with `require` expressions like below:

```
const indexRouter = require('../routes/index');

const config = require('./config');
```

EDIT: This is the `index.ts` dile:

```
import express, {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change that lines. TypeScript understands CommonJS modules with the according configuration. But since you want to replace them, I assume you want to use ES6 modules.

It's

```
import indexRouter from '../routes/index';

import config from './config';
```

Comment: Thank you, I did your suggestion and seems it works but on a new line of code `app.use('/', indexRouter);` I get a new error

Comment: `No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof import("c:/Users/A/Desktop/backend/src/routes/index")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
      Type 'typeof import("c:/Users/A/Desktop/backend/src/routes/index")' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 61 more.`

Comment: I also added the content of `index file.

Comment: @WDR I've edited my answer. Your `export` statement is not equivalent to the CommonJS export and since you didn't post the export, I assumed a CommonJS equivalent export.

Comment: I added an EDIT part to the end of my question,